# Upgraded from OS X 10.4 to 10.6, unable to repair filesystem booting from install disc

Tags: macos, filesystem-corruption

I have a MacBook which is a few years old now.  When I run the "Verify disk" command from within Disk Utility, I get a message:

```
Volume header needs minor repair
The volume Mac OS X was found corrupt and needs to be repaired.
Error: This disk needs to be repaired.  Start up your computer with another disk (such as your Mac OS X installation disc), and then use Disk Utility to repair this disk.
```

When I boot using the OS X installation disk which came with laptop and use Disk Utility there to repair the volume, it reports:

```
The volume Mac OS X appears to be OK.
No repairs were necessary.
```

When I reboot back into the normal OS and run Disk Utility again it still reports the previous error.

This laptop came with OS X 10.4.6, but has since been upgraded to OS X 10.6.x.  I presume that I'm unable to use the installation disc to repair the volume because it is too old for the upgraded operating system and filesystem.

**Without owning a physical install disc for OS X 10.6, how can I repair the volume?**

(*Note: I was able to borrow an install disc for OS X 10.6, but unfortunately this was from a 64-bit Mac and wouldn't boot, my MacBook is 32-bit only.*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to upgrade to 10.6, you would have had a retail Snow Leopard install disk.  That install disk will be able to boot on your computer.

If you do not have the install disk, you may need to purchase a new one or purchase a separate drive repair tool like Drive Genius.

Comment: Interesting...  I had a look but couldn't find an install disc in my cupboard.  I'd assumed OS X 10.6 might have been an internet upgrade that didn't come on physical media (I honestly don't remember the upgrade process).

Perhaps I should look harder for my disc..

Comment: Nope, first internet upgrade was Lion.

Comment: After finding my 10.6 install disc this did the trick.  Excellent. :)